# Linkedin post inspector - redirect 400 error

Tags: cors, seo, server-side-rendering, mern, google-crawlers

i really need you help,
i have a website i developed using mern stack, which i want to be able to share with linkedin.
i did took care of the ssr for the facebook and whatsapp crawler and they both work and show the updated og tags, but somehow the linkedin crawler just doesnt work and gives me 400 error for anypage in my website
this the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhYze.png)

what can it be?
unique header? cors?
thanks

i tried change the robots.txt

Comment: A 400 error is a "bad request."   ie your server is rejecting requests made by linkedin because it thinks they are malformed.  Is there any information in your server's error_log about it?  It is really hard to guess what the problem might be without debugging information from the logs.

Comment: thanks!
i forgot i can check error logs of the server, now i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I checked the error logs of nginx and found it was that the LinkedIn crawler uses a very very long header which causes the nginx an error 400,
so I used these two lines in the nginx `conf.d`:

```
large_client_header_buffers 8 16k;
client_header_buffer_size 8k;
```